# <meta> tags are missing from the build HTML files

Tags: html, npm, meta-tags, docusaurus

I was working on an existing Docusaurus 2 project and I was trying to add search functionality to it using the [CMF Search Plugin](https://github.com/cmfcmf/docusaurus-search-local). When I build the app, the plugin shows an error that it cannot find the `<meta>` tags in the HTML files.

When I dug further I found that the build HTML files in the `build` folder were missing all the `<meta>` tags which Docusaurus adds. When I serve my app, however, the tags are visible in the browser's Inspect window.

What should be the reason that the tags are not generated?

Here's the generated HTML output:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="generator" content="Docusaurus v2.4.1">
    <title data-rh="true"></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.12.0/dist/katex.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-AfEj0r4/OFrOo5t7NnNe46zW/tFgW6x/bCJG8FqQCEo3+Aro6EYUG4+cU+KJWu/X" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/styles.97a4b5b5.css">
    <link rel="preload" href="/assets/js/runtime~main.26d1980b.js" as="script">
    <link rel="preload" href="/assets/js/main.0dcb1770.js" as="script">
</head>

<body>
    <script>!function () { function t(t) { document.documentElement.setAttribute("data-theme", t) } var e = function () { var t = null; try { t = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("docusaurus-theme") } catch (t) { } return t }() || function () { var t = null; try { t = localStorage.getItem("theme") } catch (t) { } return t }(); t(null !== e ? e : "light") }()</script>
    <div id="__docusaurus">
    </div>
    <script src="/assets/js/runtime~main.26d1980b.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/main.0dcb1770.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**Error output**

[image: CMF Search Build Error]

Comment: can you share the error image ?

Comment: Try clearing the cache (e.g., by deleting the .docusaurus or .cache folder

Comment: @KannuMandora I've added the error message which I get after running `npm run build`.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour Tried clearing the cache. Still no change in the output.